# Multiple options for decoding cached url's

Tags: php, caching, md5

I have a script that needs to pull data from different cached URLs.

Right now $url = 'http://example.com/search.php?user=abc&part='.$part;

I need the portion of the script below modified to search multiple MD5 encrypted url's

i.e. 
$url = 'http://example.com/search.php?user=abc&part='.$part;
$url = 'http://example.com/search.php?user=xyz&part='.$part;
$url = 'http://example.com/search.php?user=123&part='.$part;

If more than 1 value is returned than return the one with the newest date.

$xid needs to be the current setting for $url

Original code.

```
    function get_cache_file($url) {
        $xid = md5($url);

        $gendir = CACHE_ROOT . substr($xid, 0, 1) . '/'. substr($xid, 1, 2);

        if(!is_dir($gendir)) {
            mkdir($gendir, 0777, true);
            }

        return $gendir . '/' . $xid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to the problem.

```
function get_cache_file($part)
{
    $users = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3');

    $file = '';
    $time = 0;

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $url = 'http://example.com/search.php?user=' . $user . '&part=' . $part;
        $xid = md5($url);

        $gendir = CACHE_ROOT . substr($xid, 0, 1) . '/' . substr($xid, 1, 2);

        if (is_dir($gendir) && is_file($gendir . '/' . $xid)) {
            if ($time < filemtime($file)) {
                $time = filemtime($file);
                $file = $gendir . '/' . $xid;
            }
        }
    }
```